# ASP.Net loading JavaScript missing main folder from root error 404

Tags: javascript

```
<script src="../js/goto.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
```

Comes back as: root/js/goto.js
should be: root/mainfolder/js/goto.js

I tried in the src="/js/goto.js" but does not work either.  I keep getting 404 error.  Running IIS10.  Works on my desktop but not thru the server.  All javascripts are doing this.  Help!

Comment: How about `src="js/goto.js"` ? `../js/goto.js` means go one folder up from the current location. `/js/goto.js` means to load that path from the webserver root.

Comment: That worked!  Thank You!